# How can I retrieve current playback time in VLC video filter module

Tags: video, vlc

I want to manipulate an image that lies within the predefined set of playback times (for example from 3 second mark to 6 second mark). However, I can't retrieve the playback time within the video filter module. The struct picture_t contains a member "date" that holds the display date but not the timestamp starting from zero when the playback started. There is apparently no way I can determine what is the current playback position especially after the user performs a seek operation using the seek bar.

So, how do I determine the current playback position within the "video filter" module that stays consistent even after a seek operation?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Edit:
Here is the sample code that will simply drop frames from 60 sec to 120 sec. If I do seek operation, these marks of 60 and 120 secs are no longer valid.

```
picture_t *Filter( filter_t *p_filter, picture_t *p_pic )
{
    filter_sys_t *p_sys = p_filter->p_sys;
    // save the start date
    if ( p_sys->start == -1 )
        p_sys->start = p_pic->date;    
    if ( p_pic->date > p_sys->start + 60000000 && p_pic->date < p_sys->start + 120000000)
    {
        picture_Release( p_pic );
         return NULL;
    }
    return p_pic;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you've got so far ;)

Comment: You can see the sample code above at least to make my point. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer for the benefit of others.

Currently, this is not possible in VLC. Instead, this can be done using a demuxer module because the demuxer knows the playback position of the track being played. It can also communicate with any other module (video filter2 for instance) using the Observer pattern implemented in VLCcore. Follow [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Hacker_Guide/Variables/) for more information on VLC object variables.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution for your question.

But this does not get the playback time directly. But it converts the frames count into time. 
So you don't have to import any function.

currently i tried this below implementation which is working:

---

```
filter_sys_t *p_sys = (filter_sys_t *)p_filter->p_sys;
strm_time = 0.04 * (double)(p_sys->i_frames);
// 0.04 implies the 25 frames per minute
```

---

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.